# Ruby sort array by child collection

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm got array of book(books). Every of my book has array of chapter(chapters). Every chapter has text. Every text has length.

I'm need order by descending all my books, depend of chapters.text.length. Did anyone know how to do it, except creating class "BookWithChaptersLength"?

Comment: Since each book has multiple chapters, you need to clarify how exactly should your sorting work. Should it be sorted by max chapter length per book? Also, how are your books represented? Do you have a `Book` class, or is it simple hash?

Comment: look into the `sort_by` method of the array class.

Comment: Try to write it and come back when you stuck.

Comment: I'm already stuck. Problem that i'm actually has tables with connections 1..* and don't know how sort they. Now i'm figured, than i'm asked wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by `max` text length of all chapters for one `book`

```
books # array of books
ascending_sorted = books.sort_by {|b| b.chapters.map{|c| c.text.length}.max }
descending_sorted = ascending_sorted.reverse
```